# '90s UK kids' series where scientists or the military had to fire a laser beam into the sky to prevent something from coming

Tags: story-identification, tv

I’ve been trying to remember a UK 1990s TV series on kids' TV sci-fi drama where scientists or the military had to fire a laser beam into the sky to prevent something from coming. I remember the sky was glowing red or it might have been on the edge of a volcano or something.

Comment: This is a very terse description. Please take a look at the prompts in [this thread](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and then [edit] your question to add any further details you may recall. The more info you can give us, the better the odds that someone can ID this for you. You might also want to take the [tour].

Comment: Fifth element came out then. In one of the parts of the Robotech saga they turned the military base at the north pole into a giant cannon, lured the enemy armada over the north pole, and then blew them up with the giant gun.

Comment: Not a TV series, but that immediately makes me think of "Howard the Duck".

Comment: Was it live action or a cartoon? also if you can remember if you watched it on the BBC or ITV that would help narrow it down. Neither of those broadcasters produced much SF in the 80's or 90's

Comment: It was live action, I can’t remember if it was itv or BBC

Comment: Ok that helps, was it british made or a US import?

Comment: @stuart here is a list of British kids TV shows... not many with SF content, Earth Warp, Aquila, Time Riders... have run down the list and see if anything stands out. Also you could check 1980s  because you didn't say Chenin the 1990s you watched it. If it was early 90's it could easily be a repeat from the mid to late 80s. https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Category:1990s_British_children%27s_television_series&pageuntil=Pablo+The+Little+Red+Fox%0APablo+the+Little+Red+Fox#mw-pages

Comment: I’m certain it was the 90’s as there was cgi effects that I’ve never seen in the 80’s. It was either British or Australian but pretty sure it was British. 
Thanks so much for the responses!

Comment: @Stuart ok I've done some hunting around and the only britsh kids sf series I can find are 1990's  remake of The Tomorrow People (british /australian coproduction by the looks of things) and a series called Delta Wave. There is hardly any info about this but there are some episodes on youtube. take a look at this and if its familiar... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bciosSnojRI